# Is eclipselink project still active?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

We are using eclipselink, with some bugs here and there. It seems to me that development is stopped. Last release was 2.6.4 with a few bugs fixed.

The list of "active" bugs is huge and the number of commits last year is very very low, and steadily decreasing.

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.eclipselink/who

There is no official word on it, but it seems to me that is not active and we should migrate as soon as possible

Comment: I think you could equally apply the question to the JPA API development process (see https://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists/users/archive/2016-12/message/0 ), since the same people are involved. Sadly Oracle are utterly uncommunicative in this respect. What JPA provider you use is your choice, since it is you that will maintain your application(s) and not Oracle.

Comment: Well, you have to make the choice based on which one is best suited for your needs, of course, but you also have to consider the project's future. I can see constant work in hibernate project, so I'm reasonably confident that hibernate will be active for a resonable time, even if there is no JPA spec progress.